# chose color to use with sf.colors

Tags: r, plot, r-sf

I'm building a static map using the `sf` package and I want my  map to have both a specific color and transparency.  I can manage to get both independently but not together.

```
library(sf)    
nc = st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE)
```

I can make the map all red simply:

```
plot(nc["SID74"], col="red")
```

produces: 
[image]

If I want to add transperency, I have to change the `col` argument and pass it a `sf.colors` call:

```
plot(nc["SID74"], col=sf.colors(n=1, alpha=0.3))
```

produces:

[image]

I have the transparency but it's the default blue and I  can't find the option to change it to red in `?sf.colors`.  I want to set the color and also have the transparency.

Any idea how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a particular color you want to use, there's no need to use the `sf.colors` function. That chooses a color palette for you. The `sf.colors` function is not the only way to set colors for your plots, it just exposes the default colors that `sf` uses if you want use them elsewhere.

If you want to adjust the transparency of an exiting color, the `scales` package has a helper function to do that.

```
plot(nc["SID74"], col=scales::alpha("red", .3))
```

You can see that `scales::alpha("red", .3)` returns

```
[1] "#FF00004D"
```

so it's basically a rgb-hex value with an extra byte for transparency. You can also use the `rgb()` function to construct similar objects.

Comment: This can also be done without loading a package, e.g., `adjustcolor("red", .3)`

Comment: @BrianDavis I'm still learning new base functions all the time. Nice catch.